# Pre element formatting is off

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pre

I'm pretty new to html and css so forgive me if my question doesn't make 100% to any veterans. I am trying to apply a formatted line of code to a website using the  element but it is using all of the white space before the lines.
 [element for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsaTf.png)
[This is how it looks when I open the code in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfZmp.png)
I've tried adding the style="white-space: pre-line;" attribute to the  element in the html but when I open the code in a browser it removes the indents that I want to be formatted into the lines.
[The incorrectly formatted lines after adding the style attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar437.png)

I am expecting the outcome to look like the image below. With the text formatted how css is normally coded and aligned to the left of the flexbox. I have tried other white-space values and nothing seems to work how I want.
[An image from my homework assignment describing how our website should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EJJb.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post code as screenshots, you can include them in your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about it. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour, because the `<pre>` element's default style is `white-space: pre;`. With that every space, new line, tab and other character are rendered as-is. So if you have spaces in the `<pre>` element before the actual text, it will be rendered.

To solve your problem, remove the spaces or tabs before the code.

Comment: Yea this fixed the issue, I thought it would I just didn't know if the format of the html was going to be a big factor. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad it works now, but according to SO's rules, please accept my answer as a solution. Thanks